# systemd is ignoring ExecStop in the unit file, runs it as part of ExecStart

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, systemd

I am trying to have several VirtualBox images start automatically on boot and to be shutdown properly on host shutdown before powering down. I have a bash script, `/usr/local/bin/vmctl.sh`,  that handles starting and stopping the guest images using calls to VBoxManage. The start call is very simple - it just runs through a list of images and calls `VBoxManage startvm --type headless "<imgname>"` then exits 0. The stop call cycles through the list and calls `VBoxManage controlvm "<imgname>" acpipowerbutton` then loops until `VBoxManage list runningvms` returns an empty list OR 60 seconds passes before it exits 0. Running the script from the command line works perfectly.

I have set up a unit file in `/lib/systemd/system/vmctl.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=VirtualBox Control
After=virtualbox.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/vmctl.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/vmctl.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `systemctl start vmctl.service`, it calls both the start and stop lines. When I call `systemctl stop vmctl.service` there is an entry in syslog that states `Stopped VirtualBox Control` but it does not do anything.

I am a total neophyte to systemd. I recently upgraded this Ubuntu box to 16.04. I'm pretty sure there's a simple explanation for this behaviour that I'm just not seeing.

Thanks!

---

Update based on Mark's suggestion:

I confirmed the syntax using `systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/vmctl.service` (after moving the file there - thanks for the tip). I then changed out the ExecStart and ExecStop as you suggested, ran `systemctl daemon-reload` and still see the same behaviour. The log shows both executing when calling `systemctl start vmctl`, but neither when running `systemctl stop vmctl`:

```
# journalctl -u vmctl | tail
.
.
.
Apr 06 19:28:18 macmi10-builder systemd[1]: Started VirtualBox Control.
Apr 06 19:28:18 macmi10-builder echo[13901]: I started
Apr 06 19:28:18 macmi10-builder echo[13904]: I stopped
Apr 06 19:28:33 macmi10-builder systemd[1]: Stopped VirtualBox Control.
```

Comment: I actually had the same problem except that i had different script names, i set [RemainAfterExit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RemainAfterExit=)=yes and it worked.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, the problem is that `vmctl.sh` immediately exits. Contrary to @Christophe's answer, forking will not work most likely, as `vmctl.sh` likely does not fork. What you need is a `oneshot` service, with `RemainAfterExit=true`. If you just change it to `oneshot`, you'll get the exact same behavior. The `RemainAfterExit` part tells it that even after the `ExecStart` exits, the service should still be considered running, so it should not run the `ExecStop`(s).

Answer (score 4):

Your `systemd` syntax is correct. Your problem is elsewhere.

First, you can confirm that the syntax itself is correct with:

```
systemd-analyze verify /path/to/your/vmctl.service
```

Second, try substituting these lines:

```
ExecStart=/bin/echo "I started"
ExecStop=/bin/echo "I stopped"
```

After running `systemctl start vmctl` or `systemctl stop vmctl`, use `journalctl -u vmctl` to check the logs. I expect you'll confirm `systemd` ran the correct commands.

Also `/lib/systemd/system` is intended for a place for *packages* to manage systemd files. Files that human's modify and manually manage are intended to go in `/etc/systemd/system`

Comment: After substituting those commands into a simple or forking service, the same behavior is reflected. For simple, `ExecStart`'s echo exits, so it calls `ExecStop`. For forking, there are no running child processes from `ExecStart`'s echo, and as such it calls `ExecStop`.

Answer (score 0):

The default Type setting for a Service unit is **Type=simple**, which is used when the process configured with ExecStart= is the main process of the service. Such a unit will wait until the process specified by ExecStart returns, then deactivate by running the process specified by ExecStop. In your case, this will happen as soon as the virtual machines have been launched (not what you want).

**Type=forking** is used when the process specified by ExecStart is expected to exit after start-up is complete, while its child process(es) continue(s) to run in the background. This is the behavior of traditional UNIX daemons and the recommended choice in your case. The process specified by ExecStop will run in case the service crashes or upon the “systemctl stop vmctl” command.

So your unit file should be:

```
[Unit]
Description=VirtualBox Control
After=virtualbox.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/vmctl.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/vmctl.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: The `vmctl.sh` script is not a daemon - it's a controller, and likely does not fork.